# xPath and Math Functions

Tags: xml, wordpress, xpath

I am trying to build an eCommerce website.  My distributor has provided me with a live XML data feed so I can essentially display their entire catalog on my website.  I am using [WP All Imports](http://www.wpallimport.com) to parse this feed into product categories, which has been a struggle to say the least.

In the XML feed they provide `{Price[1]}` which is their whole sale price.  Can I write a math function that increases this xPath by some amount?

For example

```
{Price[1]}*1.2
```

or

```
{{Price[1]}*1.2}
```

Comment: Here is what my data feed looks like   http://www.lipseys.com/webservice/pricequantity.ashx?email=william.c@cpgroup-inc.com&pass=3678hvac

Comment: Did you really want to post your username and password?

Comment: Yes, I will be changing it anyways once I solve this little problem. Besides there is nothing that anyone can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it took so long to post this answer, but I figured out the WordPress WP All Import product markup problem.

First you have to add this script to the themes function page (I chose to add it to the beginning so I wouldn't have to chase it down anytime I wanted to change my markup):

```
function add_markup($x) {
 $markup = 1.2;
 $y = $x * $markup;
 return $y;
}
```

The above script will markup your product 20%. Just edit the $markup = 1.2; to what ever you want your margin to be. Ge sure to enter it as 1.a number so it will increase your products price.  Not including a number here will reduce a products price by that percentage.  For example

```
function add_markup($x) {
 $markup = 0.3;
 $y = $x * $markup;
 return $y;
}
```

Will decrease your price by 30%.

Then in the "Regular Price ($)" box of the WP All Imports WooCommerce Products page you need to enter this exactly the way I have it typed brackets and all

```
[add_markup({Price[1]})]
```

//ScreenShot//
http://cpgroup-inc.com/images/Untitled.png

Comment: looks easy, I would like to see if it works as a "currency converter". for example adding if the currency = USD then $markup = valueindatabase . How would you make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can perform math in XPath 1.0. For example, in your supplied XML file:

```ruby
doc.xpath('//Item[ItemNo="AC45G"]/Price')
#=> <Price>422.83</Price>

doc.xpath('//Item[ItemNo="AC45G"]/Price/text()')
#=> 422.83

doc.xpath('//Item[ItemNo="AC45G"]/Price * 2')
#=> 845.66

doc.xpath('sum(//Price)')
#=> 2886778.14

doc.xpath('sum(//Price) * 2')
#=> 5773556.28
```

<sub>Tested using the Ruby library [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), which uses the very-standard [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org) under the covers for XPath.</sub>

However, the WordPress "All Imports" plugin appears to only [use XPath for filtering](http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/step-2/filtering-with-xpath/). Your best bet would be to try using the syntax `{Price[1] * 1.2}` and see if that works, since it appears that `{…}` is the delimiter for an XPath expression. You could also try `{Price[1]/text() * 1.2}` to be more explicit.

Comment: How familiar are you with this plugin?

Comment: I have no experience with WordPress or this plugin. I know XML and XPath, and read the documentation for the plugin, and I see common XPath expressions inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to offer you this as I worked on it for quite a while as there was not a solution for me. This, really is the only solution you need.
With this, you can tell WP all import that when it imports a product, it must see which price category the item falls under, then set the allocated markup.
You can download "Custom Function" plugin for WordPress, paste the below and as @WilliamCornettPMP and @Phrogz said, just put `[add_markup({Price[1]})]` in the price field when importing.

```
   function add_markup($x) {
    if ($x>0 && $x<500) 
    $markup=1.482;
    else
    if ($x>501 && $x<1000)
    $markup=1.333;
    else
    if ($x>1001 && $x<4000)
    $markup=1.231;
    else
    if ($x>4001 && $x<8000)
    $markup=1.220;
    else
    if ($x>8001 && $x<10000)
    $markup=1.197;
    else
    if ($x>10001 && $x<15000)
    $markup=1.186;
    else
    if ($x>15001 && $x<20000)
    $markup=1.186;
    else
    if ($x>20001 && $x<25000)
    $markup=1.174;
    else
    if ($x>25000)
    $markup=1.166;
    return $x*$markup;
}
```